# Replace jar and redirect import statements

Tags: java, api, jar, classloader

We have a Java program that relies on a specific library.  We have created a second library that has a very similar API to the first library, however, this one is made in-house and we are ready to begin testing it.

To test, we would like to replace the jar in the Java program with the jar of our new library.  The issue is that the new library does not have the exact same namespace, so the import statements will not align. For example,

**Java program**

```
import someLibrary.x.y.Foo;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        new Foo().bar();   
    }
}
```

**New Library has the same API but different namespace**

```
anotherLibrary.x.y.Foo;
```

**Question:** How can I use the classloader or another tool to run a Java program but replace a dependency and redirect import statements to another namespace?

[EDIT] - We do not have access to the Java program's source code. We can have this program changed to use our new library but we do not want to do that until after it has been thoroughly tested.

Comment: If you created the second library, and you just need one or the other, wouldn't it be easier to just rename your own library's package to have the correct package name?

Comment: write a program/script that can scan through all your files and replace the old with a new one.

Answer (score 1):

The only solution I can think of would involve writing a custom `ClassLoader` that would alter the bytecode to change the method references and field references to change the class name.

Answer (score 0):

How about the straightforward solution:

1. Create a branch of your main program (in git or whatever source control tool you use):
2. Apply all the changes required to work with the new library (change all the imports)
3. Deploy on test environment and test extensively
4. Merge back to master when you feel confident enough

Another solution could be:

1. Create a branch out of new library
2. Change the imports so that it will look exactly as the old one (with all the packages)
3. Substitute the old library with a new one in your application
4. Deploy on test environment and test extensively
5. When you're ready with the new library deploy to production and keep working in production for a grace period of month or something (until you really feel confident)
6. In a month change back all the imports (basically move from branch with the "old" imports to the branch with your real imports in both library and application.

**Update**

Its also possible to relocate packages of your version of the library automatically if you use maven.

Maven shade plugin has `relocate` goal that can be used to "relocate" the packages of your library to be just like packages of existing library. See [shade plugin's documentation](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/examples/class-relocation.html)

Comment: Solution 1 would not work since we do not have access to the Java program's source code. Solution 2 would work but it is something we would prefer to avoid.

Comment: I didn't realize that you dont have an access to the source code of the application, sorry. I've updated the answer with one additional option that can also work for you.